# Make Urllib2 move through pages

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2, lxml, lxml.html

I am trying to scrape http://targetstudy.com/school/schools-in-chhattisgarh.html

I am usling lxml.html, urllib2

I want somehow, follow all the pages by clicking the next page link and download its source.
And make it stop at the last page.
The href for next page is ['?recNo=25']

Could someone please advise how to do that,
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code,

```
    import urllib2
    import lxml.html
    import itertools
    url = "http://targetstudy.com/school/schools-in-chhattisgarh.html"
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
    stuff = urllib2.urlopen(req).read().encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(stuff)
    print stuff

    links = tree.xpath("(//ul[@class='pagination']/li/a)[last()]/@href")
    for link in links:
        req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
        stuff = urllib2.urlopen(req).read().encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        tree = lxml.html.fromstring(stuff)
        print stuff
        links = tree.xpath("(//ul[@class='pagination']/li/a)[last()]/@href")
```

But all its doing is going to the 2nd page and NOT going further.

Please help me

Comment: Without going into detail about the fun of parsing html and creating web spiders, I expect you're having issues where you overwrite your links variable in the last line of your loop over links.

Comment: Hi Collin, Thats true.
But how do I overcome that? Could you please advise?
Thanks

Comment: Don't overwrite the list you are iterating over while you are doing it. You could probably get away with simply appending your new links to the end of the list as you read them. You should refactor some of this into functions though and keep track of links you have already followed so you don't start going in loops.

Comment: Thanks, what I don't understand is if I am getting stuck at page 3, then without going into loop, - how will i go to page 4, 5, 6 , 7 8 and 9

Comment: In your code you are looping through the list of links from the first page, but then after you read a page inside that loop you are changing the list of links out from under the loop. If you just add the new links to the end of the list instead of overwriting the list it won't break anymore. Maybe a `while (len(links))` would make more sense visually?

Comment: I am truly sorry for asking so much from you.
But if possible, could you please write something like a code. So that I undertsand it better. The theory language is getting to complicated to understand :(

Comment: This works great, it it would still not take the new url, since
link will be  ['?recNo=25']
And I wont even be able to concatenate that with url
So it would always give me a unknwn url error :(

Comment: I assume you missed out on 

links = tree.xpath("(//ul[@class='pagination']/li/a)[last()]/@href")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect all your problems are from overwriting your list at the end of the loop. Assuming the rest of your code works, this might be a better solution.

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html
import itertools
url = "http://targetstudy.com/school/schools-in-chhattisgarh.html"
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
stuff = urllib2.urlopen(req).read().encode('ascii', 'ignore')
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(stuff)
print stuff

links = [url]
visited = []
while len(links) > 0:
    # take a link out of the list and mark it as visited
    link = links.pop()
    visited.append(link)

    # open the link and read the contents
    req = urllib2.Request(link, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
    stuff = urllib2.urlopen(req).read().encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(stuff)
    print stuff

    # for every link in the page
    for new_link in tree.xpath("(//ul[@class='pagination']/li/a)[last()]/@href"):
        # if link has not been visited yet and is not in the list to visit next
        if new_link not in links and new_link not in visited:
            # add the new link to the list of links to visit
            links.append(new_link)
```

Comment: This works great, it it would still not take the new url, since
link will be  ['?recNo=25']
And I wont even be able to concatenate that with url
So it would always give me a unknwn url error :(

Comment: That sounds like a problem with how you are using lxml - maybe you should open another question with some details?