# Urllib does not return the requested content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib2

I have two a pages that I would like to scrap:
[url_1](https://www.zoekscholen.onderwijsinspectie.nl/zoek-en-vergelijk?searchtype=generic&zoekterm=&pagina=1&filterSectoren=BVE) and [url_2](https://www.zoekscholen.onderwijsinspectie.nl/zoek-en-vergelijk?searchtype=generic&zoekterm=&pagina=3&filterSectoren=BVE)

The only difference between them it's that `url_1` is the first page while `url_2` is the third page of the same domain.

I am using `urrlib` to read the urls:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html_1 = urlopen(url_1).read()
html_2 = urlopen(url_2).read()
```

Unfortunately `html_2` has the same content as `html_1`.
Reading around, I found out that maybe this is happening because the server sees me as a bot. For that reason, I am using the `request` module the `Beautiful Soup` to parse the pages:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session = requests.Session()
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5)AppleWebKit 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"}

req_1 = session.get(url_1, headers=headers)
bsObj_1 = BeautifulSoup(req_1.text)
req_2 = session.get(url_2, headers=headers)
bsObj_2 = BeautifulSoup(req_2.text)
```

Still the content is the same. How can I fix it?

Comment: I check the url you provided, there is no third page, can you check it once?

Comment: if I am getting the problem correctly, you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853748/make-urllib2-move-through-pages

Comment: @ankur09011 If you click to the next page navigator than it will return you to the initial page. But if you copy paste the `url_2` to you browser it will direct to the page that I am referring to. And no I am not referring to that question. Can you please read again my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url_1 = 'https://www.zoekscholen.onderwijsinspectie.nl/zoek-en-vergelijk?searchtype=generic&zoekterm=&pagina=&filterSectoren=BVE'
url_2 = 'https://www.zoekscholen.onderwijsinspectie.nl/zoek-en-vergelijk?searchtype=generic&zoekterm=&pagina=3&filterSectoren=BVE'

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5)AppleWebKit 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome",
            "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    s.get('https://www.zoekscholen.onderwijsinspectie.nl/')
    req_1 = s.get(url_1)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(req_1.text, "lxml")
    print(soup1.find("div", {"id": "mainResults"}).find_all("h2")[0].text)
    time.sleep(1)
    req_2 = s.get(url_2)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(req_2.text, "lxml")
    print(soup2.find("div", {"id": "mainResults"}).find_all("h2")[0].text)
```

Outputs:

```
Resultaten 1 - 20 van 165

Resultaten 41 - 60 van 165
```

Comment: I will call you Jesus becuase you saved my weekend! What was the cause of the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help! I believe it had to do with the way you were passing the headers, after inspecting the page you can see a lot of session cookies being included. That's why I included a first request to the index page.

Comment: I am asking because if I just run it for the `url_2`: `with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    s.get('https://www.zoekscholen.onderwijsinspectie.nl/')
    req_2 = s.get(url_2)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(req_2.text, "lxml")
    print(soup2.find("div", {"id": "mainResults"}).find_all("h2")[0].text)`  then I am getting `Resultaten 1 - 20 van 165`

Comment: Yes, so you need to query the first page before getting others